# Error using custom design option visual composer with applay theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When purchasing the Applay Application theme for wordpress [it is recommended](http://demo.leafcolor.com/applay/doc/) to install [Visual Composer](http://vc.wpbakery.com/).

[image]

It looks simple enough attempting to create custom CSS, however any attempts to save the *use design options*

[image]

Gives an error:

> Design options could not be saved. Error: error evaluating function `darken`:a.toHSL not a function.

Which essentially means there is an element that cannot have no color value, that is attempted to being darkened.

[image]

I searched the theme, thinking I'd done something creating a child theme, reverted it back to the parent theme and could not solve it.

[Both reports of this on the support page were](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/comments?page=406):

> Hi, we haven’t received such complains before – please open support ticket at support.wpbakery.com and share your site credentials so our support team can help you out.

Comment: I can see that it has quite a research in presenting the question... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error is due to the apptheme's author's own inbuilt theme customisation and a lack of compatibility with Visual Composer.

I received this email repsonse from the support for Visual Composer.

> The issue is because there is an inbuilt version of Visual Composer (or the related code) present in your theme which is overriding the standalone plugin version and hence causing the issue. You will have to get rid of it. I would advise you to do so with the help of theme author, otherwise you might loose the extra elements added by him. Once this is done, you can install the standalone plugin and it will work fine. Kindly check.
>
> The theme author is the one who built the theme. In your case he is: http://themeforest.net/user/leafcolor

I decided to post this, as it may help others searching for this.